# Unable to upload file to Spring MVC with Spring Security despite full configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to upload .pdf file with jQuery AJAX to Spring MVC 5 with Spring Security 5 back-end running on Tomcat and faced multiple issues depending on Spring configuration

**NOTE:**

File upload should be available without authentication

## Front-end

**Markup:**

```
<div id="upload-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Upload</h4>
        <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="file-field input-field">
                <div class="btn">
                    <span>View...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf">
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <label>
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" id="upload-bttn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat btn">Upload</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**`csrf` header for all the requests:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

**Uploading with jQuery AJAX:**

```
$("#upload-bttn").click(function () {
    var $uploadModal = $("#upload-modal");
    const fileName = $uploadModal.find(".file-path").val();
    const extension = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    if (extension === "pdf") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData($uploadModal.find("form").get(0)),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
    } else {
        M.toast({html: 'Selected file is not .pdf'});
    }
});
```

## Back-end

General configuration looks like below. It is modified depending on the cases

**Security Initialization:**

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super(SecurityContext.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }

}
```

**Application initialization:**

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(WebAppContext.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

### Case 1 - CommonsMultipartResolver bean definition

**`CommonsMultipartResolver` bean definition:**

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(
        @Value("${max.upload.size}") Integer maxNumber,
        @Value("${max.size}") Integer maxSize) {

    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024 * maxSize * maxNumber);
    resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxSize);
    resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(maxSize);
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    try {
        resolver.setUploadTempDir(new FileSystemResource(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resolver;
}
```

I remember there was strange Spring behavior when `MultipartResolver` bean should be named "multipartResolver" explicitly. I tried both `@Bean` and `@Bean("multipartResolver")` with configuration above and had same result (despite bean above is named "multipartResolver" as per method name)

**Result:**

Error 500 - Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

### Case 2 - MultipartConfigElement in Servlet registry

- removed `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean
- added `StandardServletMultipartResolver` bean
- added `MultipartConfigElement` to `ApplicationInitializer`

**`StandardServletMultipartResolver` bean definition:**

```
@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

**Updated `ApplicationInitializer`:**

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    ...
    servlet.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(
            System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
    ));
}
```

As per Spring documentation:

> Ensure that the MultipartFilter is specified before the Spring Security filter. Specifying the MultipartFilter after the Spring Security filter means that there is no authorization for invoking the MultipartFilter which means anyone can place temporary files on your server. However, only authorized users will be able to submit a File that is processed by your application

As I need to allow not authenticated users to upload the files I tried both *before* and *after* in `SecurityInitializer` as below with the same result

```
@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
}
```

**Result:**

Error 403

## Questions

- What do I miss in the configuration?

## Thoughts

- `CommonsMultipartResolver` would be preferable as allows to drive it with Spring properties
- Something wrong with Spring Security context setup
- There is `allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"` option (did not test) which I wouldn't like to stick to as its Tomcat specific

## Updates

- With disabled Spring Security everything works properly
- `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();` remains as the only security context configuration so don't think its Security context configuration issue
- Set multipart resolver bean name explicitly in `MultipartFilter` in 
  `beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext)` and still no luck
- Adding of `_csrf` token to the request header did not work for both cases
- Realized that I miss additional `WebAppContext` class in `SecurityInitializer` constructor. Now error 500 disappeared but 403 appeared for case 1. Logging says that I have invalid `csrf` token despite I added it to the header like above
- Tried to submit the form with `csrf` token including hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>` yet the result is the same - error 403 with invalid token statement

Comment: an _Error 403_  smells like a CSRF protection problem...

Comment: @DirkDeyne did not work unfortunately. Updated the question, investigating logs

Comment: @DirkDeyne it does stink with CSRF despite I added the token to request header like above. Isn't that correct?

Comment: does it work when you disable CRSF?

Comment: @DirkDeyne yes (dummy words so stack could allow to comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of struggling:

Constructor should contain both security and application context configuration classes

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super(SecurityContext.class, WebAppContext.class);
    }

}
```

Application context (`WebAppContext`) should contain `MultipartResolver` bean definition

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(
        @Value("${max.upload.size}") Integer maxNumber,
        @Value("${max.size}") Integer maxSize) {

    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024 * maxSize * maxNumber);
    resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxSize);
    resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(maxSize);
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    try {
        resolver.setUploadTempDir(new FileSystemResource(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resolver;
}
```

In my case after application initialization `csrf` token inside Spring `CsrfTokenRepository` was empty for some reason so when Spring been comparing token from client request header with `null` in `CsrfFilter` Spring was returning error 403. I configured `csrf` in security context in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository());
    ...    
}
```

Now `csrf` token is passed in cookies with first server response to the browser and the repository generates and caches a token to compare against the one coming from the client so comparison passes successfully

Here `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` may also be declared as `CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()` if you would like to grab the token from cookie and set it into `csrf` header, but I have chosen to go with meta tags approach above